# How do I overwrite a $brand-primary value with SASS in Bootstrap 4 beta?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I've just updated to Bootstrap 4 beta and my colours got corrupted. Seems like they replaced color variables e.g. `$brand-primary` with `theme-color("primary")`. The only place where those are defined in variables.scss looks like:

```
$theme-colors: (
  primary: $blue,
  secondary: $gray-600,
  success: $green,
  info: $cyan,
  warning: $yellow,
  danger: $red,
  light: $gray-100,
  dark: $gray-800
) !default;
```

So I tried to overwrite this one with:

```
$theme-colors: (
    primary: #F5A637
);
```

In my variables.scss file overwriting. However, the compilation fails after that, any ideas?

Comment: Seems like you now have to overwrite it *before* the `$theme-colors` definition in bootstrap. See the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/22891#issuecomment-316463806) and [corresponding pull request](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/23260) from three days ago.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question. In the latest Bootstrap v4 you need to edit the $primary variable. No need to use colors maps anymore. You can also use this tool to customize Bootstrap's SASS variables, preview the changes and download your own version of the bootstrap.css file: http://bootstrap-4-live-customizer.com/.